# Full HD Emulator 1920x1080 not work at Run time

Tags: android, android-emulator

in my application there is requirement to build app for 1920x1080 device resolution.

so i had create android emulator with below configuration.

[image]

now the problem is emulator started but when i have run my ouapplication in it.
emulator screen become white so i could not see my application in it.

there is any other way to test or developer application with 1920x1080 device resolution.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

The Android Emulator doesn't have the capacity to run high resolution screen as OpenGL Renderer fails all the time. You can try Intel x86 to speed up your emulator. Download `SDK Manager>>Extras>>Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager` and install it from `<SDK>/extras/intel`. Check `Use Host GPU` on your emulator configuration.

P.S. I would suggest you to check [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) and [SocketQ](http://www.socketq.com)

Comment: i had download Genymotion plugin and tool but when i start from eclipse. emulator not started..

Comment: Try launching it from start menu or application launcher.

Comment: I guess its a bug then. I'm on Win 8 64 with 8gigs Ram. Not facing this issue. Send your feedback to support@genymotion.com and take a look at http://androvm.org/blog/

Comment: checking Use Host GPU solved the problem for me (on Fedora 19 x64 )